# Start 389 Administration Server on boot

Tags: linux, fedora, 389-ds

I am using 389 Directory Server on Fedora 18. I've been able to have 389 DS start at boot using `systemctl enable dirsrv.target`. However, this only starts the directory server itself, and not the administration server. I know it is possible to start the administration server manually using `start-ds-admin`, but how can I start the admin server automatically at boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemctl enable dirsrv-admin.service` is what you want.